# How to insert record into GreenPlum Database from Mule?

Tags: mule, greenplum, mule-studio

This question is a variation of [How to read CSV file and insert data into PostgreSQL using Mule ESB, Mule Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911296/how-to-read-csv-file-and-insert-data-into-postgresql-using-mule-esb-mule-studio/13924363#comment19218217_13924363). Earlier we had PostgreSQL but now it has been changed to GreenPlum Database. But PostgreSQL has a native support in Mule Studio but not GreenPlum Database.

How can I do this insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a [GreenPlum doc](https://sites.google.com/a/elixirtech.com/wiki/repertoire/data/jdbc-datasource/jdbc-datasource-connectivity-with-greenplum):

> Since Greenplum Database is based on PostgreSQL, end-users interact
>   with Greenplum Database (through the master) using JDBC Drivers for
>   PostgresSQL.

It seems you can use the PostgreSQL connector and point it to the GreenPlum master.