# Create Virtual Machines in VMWare ESX from a CSV file with Mule ESB

Tags: soap, vmware, mule, mule-studio, esxi

I have a requirement to create a number of virtual machines on an ESXi host from a list contained in a CSV file which contains the number of processors, disk space, RAM etc. In order to do this it is required that I use the Mule ESB and the VMWare API.

I am new to Mule and Mule Studio but I can make Mule parse the CSV (using info from [How to read CSV file and insert data into PostgreSQL using Mule ESB, Mule Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911296/how-to-read-csv-file-and-insert-data-into-postgresql-using-mule-esb-mule-studio)) and I have the WSDL for the VMware API (http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2010507) but I can't connect the two.

The CSV format is not defined yet so anything suitable is fine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not try with Perl, its simple, vSphere SDK avail at free ,
We can extract values from csv files and send them to vSphere API.

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/index.html

here they gave how to connect to vsphere, we can use web services calls to connect to vsphere. all the need is to open https port.

We can play left and right with vSphere using perl.

Answer (score 1):

You need a file inbound endpoint to pick up the CSV files, see: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Transport+Reference

And also need a CXF client with an HTTP outbound endpoint to connect to the VMWare web service, see: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF

Comment: Thanks David, I have already got the reading of the CSV sorted as per the Mule docs. I'm just not sure how to create a web service request from the data imported. Any ideas?

Comment: What issue are you facing when binding this data to the CXF client?