# How to insert excel file in database in Mule

Tags: file, mule

I have a `file:inbound-endpoint` where `excel` file will be coming in. I need to insert excel records into database. I read this answer

[How to read CSV file and insert data into PostgreSQL using Mule ESB, Mule Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911296/how-to-read-csv-file-and-insert-data-into-postgresql-using-mule-esb-mule-studio)

and it shows how to insert `csv` records into database.

1. Do I need to convert `excel` to `csv` first? If yes, can I do that just using `Mule Community Edition`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need the Enterprise Edition (DataMapper) for out-of-the-box Excel support. But you can of course create a custom transformer with something like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). If you do this, you will not need the CSV phase.